# Human/Bot validation

Tags: javascript, validation, captcha, recaptcha, bots

I know the traditional way of evaluating whether a human user is consuming your web page or a bot is accessing it. The Captcha! I have see the image captchas' and expression captchas'.

But when I visited https://goo.gl/ I saw a new kind, where there is no image or an expression, the validation is just done by clicking on a DOM element. 
There are lot of automated programs that can generate a click and thus pass the validation that is there!

I am curious to know how this will avoid the bots and validates that there is actual human, who is performing the operation. Am I missing something?

**Edit:**

I saw this [video](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html), which is on the [recaptcha home page](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) It says that they use Advance risk analysis engine.. what does that mean?

Comment: just take an input and ask a simple question sth. like "Pls enter the yellow code you find at our imprint" or "enter our zip code from the footer" this will avoid most bots

Answer (score 1):

> It says that they use Advance risk analysis engine.. what does that
>   mean?

They didn't publish how it exactly works. 
This would not make sense anyway because then it would be easier to make a bot bypass it.